# ¿Por que me da esto? TypeError: 'tiempo' is an invalid keyword argument for __new__()

Tags: python

En este ejercicio:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def informe(tiempo , combustible, destino):
    combus= combustible/3
    hora= datetime.now()
    hora_llegada = hora + timedelta(tiempo = tiempo)
    time = tiempo
    return f"""""
    Destino:
    El destino es:................{destino}
    ---------------------------------------------------
    Horario:
    Hora de salida:...............{hora} horas,
    Tiempo estimado de vuelo: ....{time} horas,
    Hora estimada de llegada: ....{hora_llegada.strftime('Hora de llegada: %A %H:%M')} horas,
    ---------------------------------------------------
    Combustible:
    Hay un total de {combustible} galones de combustible en los tanques.
    Hay un promedio de {combus} galones de combustible en los 3 tanques.
    ---------------------------------------------------
    Fin del informe.
    """
print(informe(12 , 120, "La luna"))
```

Me arroja lo siguiente:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

TypeError: 'tiempo' is an invalid keyword argument for **new**()

Sin el print, la función parece funcionar, no arroja ningún error, pero al agregar print parece que time arroja el problema, como podría solucionarlo?

Actualización: al cambiar tiempo por horas la clase delta puede trabajar, en mi mente por alguna razón los use como equivalencias y por eso fue el error

```
class datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)
```

Comment: La clase `timedelta` no tiene ningún parámetro en su constructor que sea `tiempo`. El constructor de la clase es `class datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)`, así que no se que estés intentando hacer con la variable `tiempo`.

Comment: Gracias, cierto como es la primera vez que la uso se me paso por alto eso, al cambiar tiempo por hours salio perfectamente, gracias!!